# Arquillian IT-Test Hibernate enhance

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jboss-arquillian, shrinkwrap

I'm trying to implement some IT-Testing. I'm using Arquillian. I can build a war with Shrinkwrap and everything seems to work like excepted.

My Problem, the Entity Classes are not getting enhanced from Hibernate and therefore the test fails.

My code:

```
WebArchive war = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class)
            .addPackages(true, "x.y.z.acme")
```

Error:

```
Caused by: org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.ArquillianProxyException:
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException : The type "class 
x.y.z.acme.persistence.entity.AnEntity" has not been enhanced. 
[Proxied because : Original exception caused: class 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException]
```

How could i resolve this issue? Preferable without using a second project for IT-Testing

Comment: You do not appear to be using Hibernate. It looks like OpenJPA to me.

Comment: you were right. Hibernate was not configured correct in the test war. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution myself. I forgotten to add the persistence.xml to the WebArchive. My `@Deployment` method looks now like this:

```
@Deployment
public static WebArchive createJavaTestArchive() throws IOException {
    WebArchive war = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class)
        .addPackages(
                true,
                "x.y.z.acme",
                "javax.persistence" // Tomee does not contain JPA2.1
        )
    ;
    File beansXml = new File("src/main/resources/META-INF/beans.xml");
    war.addAsManifestResource(beansXml, "beans.xml");
    File persistenceXm = new File("src/test/resources/test-persistence.xml");
    war.addAsResource(persistenceXm, "META-INF/persistence.xml");
    war.addAsResource(new File("src/main/resources/import.sql"));
    File[] libs = Maven.resolver().loadPomFromFile("pom.xml")
            .importRuntimeDependencies().resolve().withTransitivity().asFile();
    war.addAsLibraries(libs);
    System.out.print(war.toString(true));
    return war;
}
```